# I have added war file in Java application project , how can I use it in my Java class,should I have to import it

Tags: java, jsp, import, war

I have added timesheet.war file in Java application .Now how can I use it's support.jsp class

Answer (score 0):

war file is nothing but just a .jar with some extra matadata.You can import the war as a jar file and put it in web app lib.you will see project-classes.jar which contains all the compiled classes in a jar.

Or you can visit this link for further help
[https://blogs.oracle.com/chengfang/entry/how_to_run_a_war][1]